# I want to work in Switzerland, something has to do with languages, what languages are most needed there?

Tags: language-cultivation

So other than German, English, Dutch and Arabic I'm still working on my Italian should it be alright or should I put it on hold and switch to something like Polish, Czech, Danish, Norwegian, Swedish or Spanish?
Which of the above are most needed in Switzerland, whether to work as a translator or a customer support in an international company?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is not about the German language.

Answer (score 2):

In Switzerland the most people (*62.5%*) speak German (or Swiss-German), but there are **three** other *national-languages*: French (*22.9%*), Italian (*8.2%*) and Romansh (*0.8%*).
<sub>Percent-data are from 10/06/2020</sub>

But if you want to work in a *international company*, you must dominate English. Which other language you still need can’t be said. So this question can‘t be answered.